# TextEdit is not working

Tags: text-editor

TextEdit is not working.  I have tried reinstalling but every time i am getting

> You can't open the application TextEdit because it may be damaged or
>   incomplete.

message. i dont want to reinstall mac os x. i am using 10.6.8 os x. I also referred [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3131354?start=0&tstart=0) post.

[image]

Comment: Open console and watch the activity when you open TextEdit — it could greatly clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Xcode installed, you can recompile it yourself.

Go to `/Developer/Examples/TextEdit`, double click on `TextEdit.xcodeproj`, and click the play button.

In case you are Xcode less, let me know, I'll upload a build for you on my server.